# Forecasting with LSTM and use of final hidden states

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I'm working on a seq2seq, stateless (return_state = False), forecasting problem.

Let's say I have 10 independent time series with dimensions (10,50,2) where 10 is the number of samples, 50 is the timesteps, and 2 is the number of features.
If I divide this time series into training with size (10,35,2) and test (10,15,2) where I use test as a validation set for my forecasting (to find how good the trained network forecasts), since the lstm is stateless in this case, the states are flushed (reset) between batches during training (let's say batch size = 1--> train one sample at a time).

My main question is, during prediction for the test set with size (10,15,2), should I use final_hidden_states of my trained network and set it as initial_hidden_states for the test set? The reason for my question is because technically, the test set (10,15,2) is the continuation of (10,35,2) but, I'm not training on the test set.

To be more clear,
1st question is: do I really need the final_hidden_states for forecasting in this case?
2nd questions is: If I need the final_hidden_states, how can I extract them for all 10 samples since the states are flushed internally during training between each batch?

Any help is appreciated. A sample code is highly appreciated (Input and output can be arbitrary or randomly chosen).

I'm currently using keras in python.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot have different sequence size for test and training, plus it seems to me that splitting along your sequence dimension to get a train and test data set is the wrong approach. Instead I'd split the the batch into 2 ex: `train (8,50,2)` and `test (2,50,2)`

Comment: Looking back at what you said. You were right. The input has to be of the format (independent sequences, timesteps (in each sequence), num_features). What I really meant was: Each of the 10 independent time series (let's say 10 different cars) has 50 time steps for each car and I only want to train on 35 of those and use the remaining 15 for validation. I can choose a "window size = look back" of 5 timesteps for instance. So, then I would only make 35 timesteps available instead of 50 like (10,35,2) but, choosing a window size = 5, 35*10=350/5=70 I would have to feed it like this (70,5,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should answer your question [Post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/encoder-decoder-long-short-term-memory-networks/?unapproved=576428&moderation-hash=acef10543bdd70b40efa0fa6324ad9ae#comment-576428) and also clarify how Seq2Seq auto-encoder works.

Comment: Thank you Yoan. I understand what you are saying but, this approach was taken in one of the papers I was reading to evaluate how good the trained network forecasts will be and it does make sense to me because I'm generating unseen future values based on previous values and I should be able to know how good the forecasts are because in reality, I do have the actual values of the remaining 15 time steps and it would be nice to know how well my predictions are based on this "unseen" values. Think of it as a validation of my network after training.

Comment: I also need to test this on new data after the mentioned process: test it on 11th, 12th, 13th, etc. new time series to further see the validity of my network if I used 10 of the time series for training. This kind of seems like a double validation to me. The questions it answers is: How good are the forecasts and how good can it forecast on the new data (new time series). I hope this makes it more clear. Thank you for the link, I will look into it.